# truncate array fields

Tags: arrays, postgresql, decimal

I am trying to truncate value in an array of integer to 8 decimals in Postgres in a SQL SELECT statement and get back the cleaned array.

> ```
> [1.030411088488374,1.0985247734044379,1.0863039797613594]
> ```

Comment: What is the result you expect?

Comment: Expected result : 

    [1.03041108,1.09852477,1.08630397]

Answer (score 1):

You need to unnest the array, truncate every element, then aggregate the elements back into an array:

```
select array_agg(trunc(n, 8) order by idx)
from unnest(array[1.030411088488374,1.0985247734044379,1.0863039797613594]::numeric[]) with ordinality as t(n,idx);
```

If you need to do that a log, consider creating a function:

```
create function trunc_elements(p_numbers numeric[], p_num_digits int)
  returns numeric[]
as
$$
  select array_agg(trunc(n, p_num_digits) order by idx)
  from unnest(p_numbers) with ordinality as t(n,idx);
$$
language sql;
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, WITH ordinality seems not to be recognized

Comment: @OwenS: then you are using an [unsupported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) Postgres version. If you do not need to preserve the original order of the elements, you can just leave it out.

Comment: @OwenS: as I said: if you don't need to preserve the element order, you can just leave it out.